# Static or Dynamic addresses when connecting to a SAN

Tags: networking, dhcp, pxe, san

Best practices question: I have many computers connected, in the same rack, to a SAN. The SAN talks iSCSI to the network, and will need to have an IP address to serve out storage. The question is if the computers on the network should have DHCP or static IPs.

So far I've heard that static IPs are best for connecting to a SAN, so the resource is available even wihtout a DHCP server. Fewer moving parts, more reliability. However, this presents an issue when I don't care about individual computers in the rack. They all will PXEboot anyway, and I'll likely only identify them by their MAC addresses instead of physical location or other such trivia.

What is the best practice in a datacenter, or what factors should I keep in mind when deciding?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PXE to make the servers boot, then it makes sense to use DHCP.

You can assign static IPs within DHCP - but be careful, if you're using iSCSI root devices without a HBA (iPXE and so on) you can't change the IP after boot time because it will disconnect your root iSCSI device.

Windows (when netbooting over iSCSI) will get two IP's at boot, one from iBFT and one from DHCP Client Service. Disable DHCP Client Service on netbooted Windows devices. Linux is guilty of this as well - remove NetworkManager and similar software from the PXE image.